# Universal routes for both authenticated and unauthenticated users

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-sanctum

I'm creating an application with Laravel and React using Sanctum. Some routes must be universal and accessible to both logged-in and logged-out users. I want to display different information based on the user's authentication status. The problem is that only when I use the `auth::sanctum` middleware I can check if I am logged in (`Auth::check()`) or display information about the currently logged-in user if there is one (`Auth::user()`). I've searched for a solution, including here. I found several posts, but none solved my problem. I've tried using `$request->user('sanctum')` or attempted to use a middleware like this:

```
class AuthSanctum
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->bearerToken()) {
            Auth::setUser(
                Auth::guard('sanctum')->user()
            );
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I want to create a controller method where I will check if the user is logged in, and if so, I want to be able to retrieve user data. How can I achieve this, and why isn't it working for me? As I mentioned earlier, the solutions I've found are not working for me. Hence, this new post.

@Edit
I tried to use Auth::user() or Auth::check() without any middleware, but all the time, it returned a null or false (depending on whether the first or second option was used).

@Edit2
I'm using HttpOnly Cookie. It looks like this.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        return response([
            'error' => 'Invalid Credentials'
        ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    $user = Auth::user();

    $token = $user->createToken('token')->plainTextToken;

    $cookie = cookie('jwt', $token, 60 * 24);
    return response([
        'username' => $user->username
    ])->withCookie($cookie);
}
```

@Edit3
Into index.js, I configure axios like this

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost/api/";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Into login.jsx I have this code to login and store data via mobX

```
  const submit = async (value) => {
    setInProgress(true);
    await axios
      .post("login", {
        email: value.email,
        password: value.password,
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const dataJSON = data;
        setInProgress(false);

        UserStore.storeUser({
          username: dataJSON.data.username,
          avatar: dataJSON.data.avatar,
        });
        setRedirect(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setInProgress(false);
          setCantLogin(true);
        }, 200);
      });
  };
```

And I have this addiotonal code into App.jsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
    i18n.changeLanguage("pl");
    axios.get("/user").then((data) => {
      const dataJSON = data;
      UserStore.storeUser({
        username: dataJSON.data.username,
        avatar: dataJSON.data.avatar ? dataJSON.data.avatar : null,
      });
    });
  });
```

@Edit4
for example I want to get data with profile

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
      //more reuqests
    }); 
  });
```

In this example I have a loop and page doesn't work correctly. I need do that in my all pages?

@Edit5
I'm not sure that I udestood you correctly. After login i add request to this endpoint. XSRF appears in cookies what you can seed at the  screen but the problem persists.
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHzXO.png)
My code to login looks like this

```
  const submit = async (value) => {
    setInProgress(true);
    await axios
      .post("login", {
        email: value.email,
        password: value.password,
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const dataJSON = data;
        setInProgress(false);

        UserStore.storeUser({
          username: dataJSON.data.username,
          avatar: dataJSON.data.avatar,
        });
        const url = "/sanctum/csrf-cookie";
        fetch(url).then(() => {
          alert("udało się");
        });
        setRedirect(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setInProgress(false);
          setCantLogin(true);
        }, 200);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

-1-remove the middleware from the 'generic' route

-2-check directly in the controller if the request is coming from an authenticated user with Auth::guard('sanctum')->check() and return the appropriate response based on that

**EDIT**

please work with your devtool open so you can inspect the requests.
modify the login like this:

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

 public function login()
{
    
    request()->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required'],
    ]);

    /**
     * We are authenticating a request from our frontend.
     */
    if (EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::fromFrontend(request())) {
        
        $this->authenticateFrontend();
    }
    /**
     * We are authenticating a request from a 3rd party.
     */
    else {
        
        // Use token authentication.
    }
}
```

When sending the sanctum/csrf request inspect devtool and make sure it is successful, then in devtool click Application->storage->cookies->name of your app and make sure laravel_session and XSRF-TOKEN are set.

Now when making the login req inspect the request headers and make sure cookie and X-Xsrf-Token are sent.

now it should work.

Comment: I tryed that. All the time controller's method return false if I don't use auth:sanctum middleware

Comment: please see edited point -2-

Comment: I tryed that but it doesn't work

Comment: strange, i tested in a  react native app and it worked, i tested by sending the bearer token in some requests and by not sending it in others, what happen to you?

Comment: I'm using HttpOnly cookie. I updated my post

Comment: please add the react request also

Comment: I show my React code. Yo can look at this.

Comment: Do you have idea why it doersn;t work?

Comment: the thing is your method of authentication does not exist as session based auth require a csrf token as explained here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#spa-authenticating, the api/mobile auth require an access token to be sent in the header. you are instead creating the access token put it in a cookie and send it back to laravel on subsequent requests. the strange thing is you said you were able to have successful auth call if the middleware was present i would have said it never works. how to solve? follow docs for session based auth and make sure XSRF-TOKEN is sent every request

Comment: Could you show me some exampole? I need to send request all the time if I want to get data from server?. In my main post i show and exmaple but it doesnt work

Comment: when user click the login button->first call to /sanctum/csrf-cookie->then call to laravel login endpoint (you are doing the opposite), and use always axios for your requests (not fetch)

Comment: have a look at this tutorial it has all you need https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mLSy4C-1iA

Comment: I add only header `axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"` becouse I don't see any more problems. But it doesn't work

Comment: at this point you may share the repository with the code or make one